# Shell script with a cron job to kill a python file named healthcheck.py if not running and start the service again?

Tags: python, shell

I am new to UNIX / Linux and need a shell script to kill a programs if it is not running. The program's name is `healthcheck.py`. This program is supposed to run this health check service for routers. But for every 8 hours the service is dropping with an error so I thought of putting it in cronjob that check if the service is running every minute and if it doesn't, I need a shell script to start the process. Currently I am doing it manually using these commands:

```
#getting the pid
 pid= ps - ef | grep -i python healthcheck.py

#kill the healthcheck.py process with the pid we got from above command
kill -9 "pid"

#running the service again
nohup python healthcheck.py &
```

Comment: Huh? You can't kill a job if it's not running. If it's not running, it's already dead. Your script has all the right ideas, but add a shebang at the first line and make sure you set a PATH that includes your Python interpreter.

Comment: Will this also work ?

ps -aux | grep -i 'healthcheck' | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9
nohup python <path_to_file> &
cat nohup.out

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?  There are tools that will handle starting, killing, restarting, processes for you.

Comment: `ps | grep | awk` is a common [antipattern](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.htm#grep). If you have `pkill`, use that instead of reinventing it poorly.

Answer (score 1):

Under Fedora you would use a systemd script for this.

Answer (score -1):

This script worked

```
ps -aux | grep -i 'healthcheck' | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9
nohup python <path_to_file/healthcheck.py> &
cat nohup.out
```

with the `crontab` entry

```
0 1 * * * cron.sh
```

Comment: Are both the server and the watcher called `healthcheck.py`?